# JavaScript testing promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a function which recives a promise like this

```
{
state: 'fulfilled'
value:[Array]
}

function register (foo) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO....";
        connection.query(query, [foo.value.from, foo.value.id], (err, res, fields) => {
        if(err){
            return undefined //this will change
        }
        return foo
        })
    })
}
```

The thing is I am returning, non rejecting neither resolving. So when Im testing..

```
    it('insertion error', function () {
        var res = 'error'
        connection = {
            query: (query, input, cb) =>{
                return cb(res, null, null)
            }
        }
        let database = proxyquire('path/to',{
            './connection': connection
        })

        var input = 
        {
            value: {

        id: 'bar',
        data: [],
        from: 'foo'
        }}  


        return database.register(input)
        .then( (result) => {
            expect(result).to.be.undefined
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err)
            err = new Error (`Test fail: ${err}`)
            throw err;
        })
    })
```

The function works well, Im pretty sure of that.
The other thing I'm sure of is that the THEN/CATCH condition never shows up. I know if I replace the return for resolve it will show up, but I need to be returned.

What should I modify, or how should I test it.

Comment: No. Just fix it. A promise that is not resolved or rejected is broken. The function does not work well.

Comment: *Why* do you think that you "need it to be returned"?

Comment: the function works well, as I said it is receving a promise. When you receive a promise, and you dont resolve or reject itm just return something it will replace that 'something' into the value field

Comment: The reason you do `(err)?reject(err):resolve(foo)`is so the promise you are returning is rejected or resolved based on your query failing or succeeding. Returning from a callback has no use for the function receiving the promise.

Comment: @JulianMendez Well no, that's not how promises work. The return value of the `new Promise` executor callback is ignored, and of course you're not returning from that anyway but you are trying to return from the `connection.query` callback which is impossible.

Comment: @JulianMendez Maybe you are confusing this with `then` callbacks, from which you can `return` just fine?

Comment: @JulianMendez If you cannot give us a convincing reason why you cannot just use `resolve` and `reject` as proper, that's your answer.

Comment: the Bergi answers weren't really convincing. May be you are right @HMR, I can't get the Promise result if I return the value directly

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example how can you make a promisse, in this example you can send true or false in the register() function.

```js
function register ( foo ) {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) =>{
         if(foo){
            resolve('Done');
         }else{
            reject('Error')
         } 
   } )
}


register(false).then( result=>{
   document.write('promisse success... ', result);
} ).catch( error => {
   document.write('promisse error... ', error);
} )
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The OP knows how to use `resolve` and `reject`, he just doesn't want to use them.

Comment: as @Bergi said, I know how to use a promise, "I know if I replace the return for resolve it will show up, but I need to be returned."